# How to change "string "numbers on a website using JS

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have this problem where I have a wallet with $25 displayed on the website. This is the where the wallet is located:

```
<p id="wallet"></p>
```

In the JS I want the user to input what they want to buy(this isn't real money just virtual money using integers). If they want cake, they input that, then click the button to display their order. However simultaneously, I want the number(wallet) to reduce per cost. Cake = $5. Therefore, buying cake should reduce $25 - $20. Nothing I try works. I tried using parseInt() but I don't know why it's not changing it on the website and I don't fully understand when and why to use it since I'm new to JS. It's only changing the wallet in the console as an integer. I tried this :

```
var wallet = document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = 25 //Makes the <P> an integer number hopefully
var cake = 5; //cost of cake

if(input == "cake"){ 
    wallet - cake;// If user inputs cake then subtract from wallet the cost of the cake
}
```

It does subtract. Unfortunately only in the console not for the user to see. Meaning the user still sees $25.

***ESSENTIALLY:***
I want to change the innerHTML from 25 to the amount of remaining money the user has :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
var wallet = document.getElementById('wallet')
var cake = 5; //cost of cake
let input = "cake";
if(input == "cake"){ 
    wallet.innerHTML -= cake;// If user inputs cake then subtract from wallet the cost of the cake
}
```

```html
<p id="wallet">25</p>
```

Comment: Bro/Sis Idk how your so smart but you just made me look like an idiot lmaoo. That was so simple omg. Thanks a lot man :D

Comment: @AaronHazzard No problem :). Please consider accepting my answer if it helps.

Comment: How do I? I'm kinda new to this

Comment: @AaronHazzard Just click the checkmark beside the post. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)